# How to call "Welcome to Mail" View Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to show "Welcome to Mail" view programmatically? 
http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT4810/HT4810_01--welcome-001-ru.png

Thank you.

Comment: This view belongs to the Mail app.  Are you trying to show something similar in your own app?  You'll have to create the view yourself.  Start with a UITableView, grouped type.

Comment: I don't want do create my custom view and just call standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of your comments you said

> But what if user didn't have any account or didn't log in with existing account?

You should just give the user a notification to tell them that they need to set up an email account first. You might be able to open the mail app to encourage them to do this using the `mailto:` url scheme [[link]](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Mail)

Answer (score -1):

You can't. This is from the settings app (mail, contacts, calendars --> add new account). What are you intending to do with it? Alter the device email settings? You won't be able to do that, either.

If you could tell us what it is you want to achieve, there may be more detail we can give you.

Comment: In my application I have button "email" which should open "send mail" view. I implemented it using MKMailComposer. But what if user didn't have any account or didn't log in with existing account?